# How to name dependent return type of template

Tags: c++, c++14

Using `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional` we can create template functions whose return type depends on their template parameters, as per the `std::enable_if` [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Example):

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value>::type 
construct(T*) 
{
    std::cout << "default constructing trivially default constructible T\n";
}
```

(shortened for brevity)

How can we define a typename usable in the function body for this return type?

Unfortunately, as cautioned in the [notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes) of the same article, we cannot just put the conditional expression into a named template parameter:

> default template arguments are not accounted for in function template equivalence

```
/* WRONG */
 
struct T
{
    enum { int_t, float_t } type;
 
    template<typename Integer,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>>
    T(Integer) : type(int_t) {}
 
    template<typename Floating,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>>
    T(Floating) : type(float_t) {} // error: treated as redefinition
};
```

We could of course copy the definition into a using-directive in the first line of the function body, but then we would have to maintain both definitions - and nested `std::conditional_t` are not exactly the pinnacle of legibility (just way, way better than old school CRTP).

Is there a way to name the type without duplicating its definition?

Comment: Do note that while `template<typename Integer, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>>` doesn't work, `template<typename Integer, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, bool> = true>` will as now the enable if isn't a default value but the type of a non-type template parameter with a defaulted value.

Comment: When you ask "How can we define a typename usable in the function body for this return type?" you don't seem to realize that the return type is actually just `void`. The example you linked just illustrates how to enable a function using SFINAE on the return type. It's not clear from your question what you really want to achieve: T is perfectly usable within the function body as it is.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike: Yes, that is pretty verbatim the Notes part I omitted, because it does not help: There is still no name for the type. I omitted it because, in a manner of speaking, the correct form lacks a name "even harder" than the incorrect form - whereas the incorrect form _if only it were not incorrect_ could indeed be used to name the type and use its name in the function body.

Comment: @Zsar What name are you looking to get?

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike: I want to name a return type that I define e.g. via `std::conditional_t`.
(I used `std::enable_if` in the question, because usage is the same and the cppreference article for `std::conditional_t` does not mention the same pitfall (using a second template parameter's default value) and instead references `std::enable_if`.)

Comment: Name you seems to look provide from first template parameter, no?

Comment: You might still provide alias in the class, for brievity.

Comment: Mmh, I hope this helps: I want to name the return type "franky".
franky is defined e.g. as `std::conditional_t<isFrankyAnIntegral, uint32_t, float>` and does not have a name, if the function is declared `template<typename iTellYouWhetherFrankyIsAnIntegral> std::conditional_t<isFrankyAnIntegral, uint32_t, float> theFrankyFunction()`. ... Now, if `isFrankyAnIntegral` depends on `iTellYouWhetherFrankyIsAnIntegral` - where do I call franky franky?

Comment: @Jarod42 : There is no class?

Comment: Can you add to the Q some pseudo code that details what you actually want to do?

Comment: @zsar I have added a response that should cover what you asked for.

Comment: `template <bool b> using Franky = std::conditional_t<b, uint32_t, float>;` then `Franky<b> foo();`?

Comment: Writing code with `std::enable_if` whereas your question is about `std::conditional_t` leads to confusion...

Comment: Well, blame cppreference for this one, as it just links to std::enable_if from std::conditional, so I used the text for std::enable_if as a base for my assumptions, not the text of std::conditional. ... Maybe I should clean up the question, now that we have arrived at a solution - though it is a bit of a shame, as it was all based on my own misunderstanding. I think it will be better left in its current state and with its current downvotes, to eventually be hidden and purged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you linked and took inspiration from aims at *enabling* a function using SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) on the return type. `std::enable_if`, if not instructed otherwise, resolves to a type that, if the substitution succeeded, contains a `type` field which is an alias for the `void` type. In essence, the return type of the example function is just void, if the substitution succeeds, otherwise the function gets discarded and compilation proceeds (SFINAE).

Reading your question, I had understood you want to replicate that behavior on your class constructors, that is enable/disable them according to the type of the constructor's argument, in which case the syntax that would make it work could be the following.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct T
{
    enum { int_t, float_t } type;
 
    template<typename Integer,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Integer>>* = nullptr>
    T(Integer) : type(int_t) {}
 
    template<typename Floating,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<Floating>>* = nullptr>
    T(Floating) : type(float_t) {}
};
```

`std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<Floating>>*` will expand to `void*` if the substitution succeeds, and therefore the template parameter will be pointer to void, that is a "non-type" parameter, which we default to `nullptr`. It works, compared to your previous example, because the non-type template parameter could have any other value, whilst `void` would be the same in both of your constructors in your attempt, hence the compiler would see that as a redefinition.

But by reading your comments to your own question, I think I understood what you really want to achieve.

The following function, named the way you named it [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681352/how-to-name-dependent-return-type-of-template#comment135192763_76681352), has a return type with the name `Franky` that depends on the first template parameter (which is also the type of the function argument itself) and can be freely used within the function's body.

```
template <typename iTellYouWhetherFrankyIsAnIntegral, 
          typename Franky = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<iTellYouWhetherFrankyIsAnIntegral>, uint32_t, float>>
Franky theFrankyFunction(iTellYouWhetherFrankyIsAnIntegral v) {
    return Franky();
}
```

Comment: Is this only incidentally safe, as long as the preceeding arguments are unique between all possible instantiations or would this break in such cases due to "default template arguments are not accounted for in function template equivalence"? I had understood that this is _not_ a universal solution and should _not_ be attempted.

Comment: Elaborate the cases which you think would not be safe. Are you going to have overloads of the same function? Why? What's the use case here? As far as your question goes, that is what you have asked for and that is the response. See it working on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/o5WP6hx6h

Comment: I think I have figured out, whence from the confusion. It should always be safe, because the template parameter we add would not exist if we returned whatever, that is: all other template parameters must already form a "Primary Key" of sorts for identifying the function, so it can never matter that our default value would not differentiate between different instantiations. ... Well, I hope this is so, and I am not making another mistake in thinking so. "It works on some compilers" does not suffice, of course - there are many UBs that "just work" on many compilers and for many platforms.

Comment: ... But yes, I think this is fine. A bit of a shame - I had that solution before I posted the question and deemed it unsafe, apparently in error. Anyway, have your Accept mark, you have certainly earned it.